# GCC for ARM -- ELF output file segment misplaced

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, linker-scripts

**Edited to add:** I have now cross-posted this to the [GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/677514) site, as I am fairly certain that it's a linker bug.

Also, I have noticed that it seems to happen when the first program segment fits into the first page in the ELF file (i.e. its starting offset within its page is >= the number of bytes in the ELF header). In this case the segment erroneously gets extended downwards to the beginning of the file. This would explain why the problem disappears if the in-page offset of the start address is reduced from 0x80 to 0x40.

---

I am implementing a stand-alone OS for ARM Cortex M0, and I have a weird problem with the linker. Here is my source file `OS.c`, stripped down to illustrate the problem:

```
int EntryPoint (void) { return 99 ; }
```

And here is my linker script file `OS.ld`, simply assigning all code to the region starting at `0x10080`:

```
MEMORY
  {
  NVM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10080, LENGTH = 0x1000
  }

SECTIONS
  {
  .text 0x10080 :
    {
    OS.o (.text)
    } > NVM
  }
```

I compile and link it:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -march=armv6-m -mthumb -c OS.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -oOS.elf -Xlinker --script=OS.ld OS.o -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

And now when I list the program segments with `readelf OS.elf -l`, I get:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x10080
There are 1 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00010000 0x00010000 0x0008c 0x0008c R E 0x10000
```

According to this, the one and only program segment starts at offset `0x000000` in the ELF output file, which is crazy: that region contains ELF header info irrelevant to the OS. And the physical start address is `0x00010000`, which doesn't exist in my hardware.

But the weird thing is that if I change both instances of `0x10080` to `0x10040` in the linker script file, it works! I get:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x10040
There are 1 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x010040 0x00010040 0x00010040 0x0000c 0x0000c R E 0x10000
```

Now the program segment is in the right place in the file, and has length `0x0000c` instead of `0x0008c`. Unfortunately address `0x00010040` doesn't exist in my hardware either, so this is not a solution.

Is this a bug in the GCC ARM compiler? Running it with `--version` gives:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2018-q2-update) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
```

Comment: I guess I have been seeing that for many years and not noticed this nuance, the elf file works just fine though with objcopy or openocd or other things like that.  since you are using gcc to call ld instead of calling ld directly you should also include the version of ld you are using.

Comment: launchpad is there for legacy reasons yes? and is a place to get pre-builts, you should if anything to go binutils support for something like this.  my binaries are built directly from sources and show the issue (for many years now a number of major revisions of gcc and/or a number of versions of binutils, possibly back to 1.x.x)

Comment: there are easier ways to get the entry point where you want it btw...imo...still interestingly will show this issue you described for certain addresses but not others.

Comment: @old_timer: The entry point is fine, I don't have a problem with that. The problem is that the code segment starts at a non-existent address. So when my own software reads the segment from the ELF file, it sees an invalid address. I have fixed my software to ignore this particular error, but it would be nice not to have to.

Comment: yep, been seeing this for years as mentioned, and agree with you that would be nice to understand.  did you confirm the problem wasnt with readelf?  (did you examine the elf file yourself?)

Comment: @old_timer: yes, I certainly did examine the ELF file. My own software needs to read it in, and this is where the problem surfaced.

Comment: just confirming, I see the same in the elf file.

Answer (score 2):

what you see might not be what you expect, but is nevertheless correct, IMHO.

ELF was created for System V. An OS that supports virtual memory and `mmap()` (a system call to map the contents of a file into memory).

You are looking at the ELF program header (**not** the section headers, see below). The program header is information to a (virtual memory capable) operation system's ELF loader about where it is supposed to `mmap()` the (complete) ELF file into virtual memory it prepared as process image. This OS would then just allocate one (or more) page(s) somewhere, call that (virtual) 0x10000 (for that process), map the file and jump to 0x10080 (the entry point).

For your second example, this would not work as you specified the (virtual) start address **before** the end of the ELF file's header (ELF header + program header + section headers), sot it cannot just map the file to a page boundary, making it more complicated (or even impossible) to the OS to do it's `mmap()` trick.

For your bare metal OS (that most likely doesn't support virtual memory, at least not on startup), the ELF program header's information is probably completely irrelevant.

You should probably rather look at the section headers, instead. They describe physical memory.

Comment: No, it's not right. If the page offset of the first region is less than the size of the ELF file header, then it gets mapped correctly to the second page in the file, at the correct offset within the page. The OS can still do its "map trick" if it wants, and my program can load the segment directly into existing memory.

Comment: I tried loading the individual sections instead of the program segments. But this leaves out initialised RAM data that the OS is supposed to copy from NVM into RAM at program startup. I was rather surprised by this, but I couldn't find a work-around.

Comment: By the way, I have jury-rigged a fix: I created an extra dummy segment in the linker script file, simply for the purpose of growing the ELF file header beyond 0x80 bytes. Now everything works hunky-dory, but I can't shake the feeling that I did something naughty.

Comment: your M0 doesn't have an MMU and - consequently - doesn't have virtual memory.

I would assume you have no choice than loading the individual sections to physical memory.

Comment: As I said, loading the individual sections doesn't work. I have to load the segments, because otherwise I lose the copy-on-load RAM data. And I am certain that this is a bug in the linker, because its behaviour is qualitatively different depending on what the size of the ELF file header happens to be.

Comment: what is 'copy-on-load RAM data'?

Comment: The `.data` section, that contains the values of initialised RAM variables. In an embedded system, the OS must copy this data from NVM to RAM on system startup. So the `.data` section has an NVM address, and a RAM address. These values are present in the NVM program segment, but for some reason, there is no section in the ELF file that contains them.

Comment: you are aware that your test program does not contain any static data (because it doesn't need any) and - even if there was one - your linker script does not contain any instructions on how to deal with it? On embedded systems, it's usually the duty of the C startup code to copy `.data` and clear `.bss`. And, btw., we usually do not have an OS on embedded systems but rather call the initial code "bootloader".

Comment: @omfr: yes, of course I am aware of all that. My real OS contains initialised RAM data (not "static" data) and a routine to copy `.data` from NVM to RAM. It is this `.data` region that is missing from the sections list.

Comment: then the problem is most likely in your linker script. I have a `.data` section in mine.

Comment: So do I. But the question was complicated enough already. And the problem is in the linker, not my linker script -- it is already apparent from my pared-down example.

Comment: I didn't mean I have a .data section in my linker script, I meant I have one in my ELF file's section list. If you don't have one, you either have no .data or there is a problem with your linker script.

Comment: @omfr: That's where it gets a bit complicated. There is a `.data` section in the ELF file, but it is mapped into RAM, not NVM. I have to load the data into NVM, so that the OS can copy it to RAM (this is a simulation). But I think I'll call it a day here. I've got things working, which is the important thing. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: I can create this problem with different linker scripts that have no confusion or fancy features of any kind are incredibly simple.  I have been able to somehow load files and run them from this weirdness not sure how at this point.  the elf file is most definitely incorrect, the offset in the header is not filled in it is zero which points at ELF at the front of the there is no way to perceive this any other way than a bad file.   subtle changes to the base address though will make this go away or come back again.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar issue with GNU linker for ARM Cortex-M platform (*GNU ld (Atmel build: 508) 2.28.0.20170620*). I had bootloader and application projects where linker from application was placing ELF headers in flash location where bootloader code is. I'm not an expert but this modification tricked my linker not to put ELF header in memory space before entry point address (will try to show on your example):

1. redefine NVM space by including first 0x80 bytes

   ```
    NVM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000, LENGTH = 0x1000+0x80
   ```
2. in sections part add that offset:

   ```
    SECTIONS
    {
        .text :
        {
            . += 0x80;
            OS.o (.text)
        } > NVM
    }
   ```

I'm not sure if this can work in your case but perhaps can be used as a hint for others.

Answer (score 0):

for arm gcc

```
arm-none-eabi-ld --help | grep page
  -n, --nmagic                Do not page align data
  -N, --omagic                Do not page align data, do not make text readonly
  -z common-page-size=SIZE    Set common page size to SIZE
  -z max-page-size=SIZE       Set maximum page size to SIZE
```

if you want your program header start address match the entry address
just set `LDFLAGS += -z max-page-size=0x80` or `LDFLAGS += -n`